# R Make a list based on other list with different lenghts

Tags: r, list, dataframe, row

I've obtained a list with diferent lenght of rows, that is, I have movies, books, magazines, web's

```
a<-(movies, books,magazines, web)
```

and I have obtained 500 movie's names, 498 name's book, 469 magazine's name and 516 web's name, all thos values are contained in an object list (list is called e); so, I have a list of 4 but I can't use view(e)

> View(e)
>   Error in View : arguments imply differing number of rows: 500, 498, 469, 516

I have to use $ to check the values per each "variable"

```
e$movies
```

So, I want to create something like this:

```
Variables   Value
movie       Dr. No
movie       From Russia with Love
movie       Goldfinger
movie       Thunderball 
books       Around the World in Eighty Days
books       Journey to the Center of the Earth
magazine    Automotive News
magazine    Bloomberg Businessweek
magazine    Motor Trend
magazine    Aviation Week & Space Technology
magazine    Black Enterprise
```

I want to change it to data.frame because I will have more variables (around 10 000) and per each variable, I will have around 500 values, so will be really difficult to use $ per each variable. Also, I was thinking to pass the new data.frame into a .csv to make others modifications.
Thanks by your help!

Comment: If you do this `a <- c(movies, books, magazines, web)` then you can access using the `$` as in `a$books` etc. So better to keep them as a list - unless there is a reason to make it a `data.frame`

Comment: Hi Suren, I want to change it to data.frame because I will have more variables (around 10 000) and per each variable I will have around 500 values, so will be really difficult to use $ per each variables. Also I was thinking in pass the new data.frame into a .csv

Comment: What is the class of each list element?

Comment: The data into the lists of 10 000 variables are character.
So, I was thinking to pass it as the example in the answer to Excel, because  I want to made modifications to the data too. Thanks by your help!

Comment: @CatCaller I don't get why you are doing this still. But what you can do is pad all the shorter ones by `NA`s, and then get them into a `data.frame`.

Comment: Do you refer something like this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11809854/insert-na-values-into-dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `stack`...

```
a <- list(movies=c("ab","cd","ef"),
          books=c("zy","xw"))

df <- stack(a)

df
  values    ind
1     ab movies
2     cd movies
3     ef movies
4     zy  books
5     xw  books
```

Comment: Dear Andrew Gustar,
Thank you so much by your answer, it works with my database of 10000!

Answer (score 0):

We could use `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
enframe(a) %>% 
    unnest
# A tibble: 5 x 2
#  name   value
# <chr>  <chr>
#1 movies ab   
#2 movies cd   
#3 movies ef   
#4 books  zy   
#5 books  xw
```

#### data

```
a <- list(movies=c("ab","cd","ef"),
      books=c("zy","xw"))
```